# ActiveModel Serializer::Pagination not working with ActionController::Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, kaminari

**Setup**:

Rails 5, using ActiveModel::Serializer and Kaminari

**Sample code**:

```
def index
  @catalogs = Catalog.page(params[:page])

  render json: @catalogs, adapter: :json_api
end
```

**Problem**:

When `params[:page]` is `nil`, my result is as expected:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "a020ab21-9028-4bfd-8f9c-1b735ed4734b",
            "type": "catalogs",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "First",
                "locale": "en"
            }
        }
    ],
    "links": {
        "self": "http://localhost:3000/v1/catalogs?page%5Bnumber%5D=1&page%5Bsize%5D=1",
        "next": "http://localhost:3000/v1/catalogs?page%5Bnumber%5D=2&page%5Bsize%5D=1",
        "last": "http://localhost:3000/v1/catalogs?page%5Bnumber%5D=3&page%5Bsize%5D=1"
    }
}
```

However, when I make a Postman call to the "next" URL (http://localhost:3000/v1/catalogs?page%5Bnumber%5D=2&page%5Bsize%5D=1),

I get:

```
Started GET "/v1/catalogs" for 172.18.0.1 at 2017-09-08 15:27:04 +0000
undefined method `to_i' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x0000c68977f718>
Did you mean?  to_s
               to_h
```

Is there something different that has to be done with Rails 5 params to get pagination for ActiveModel::Serializers to work?

Answer (score 1):

It appears params[:page] doesn't hold the page number, but a "hash": `{ number: 1, size: 1 }`. That said, you want to use the page number as the argument to `page`:

```
 def page_params
   params.fetch :page, {}
 end

 @catalogs = Catalog.page(page_params[:number])
```

Maybe even call `.per(page_params[:size])` too, to let the API change that as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I encountered nested pagination params problematic in some cases. You could use params `page` and `per_page` instead of `page[number]` and `page[size]`. Solution for `will_paginate` is in [this comment on GitHub issue](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1823#issuecomment-233223148). Solution is probably also for `kaminari`, because its the issue of serialization gem, not pagination gem.

**Explanation:**

As [Leonel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637094/leonel-gal%C3%A1n) explained, link that you are clicking:

```
localhost:3000/v1/catalogs?page%5Bnumber%5D=2
```

is the same as:

```
localhost:3000/v1/catalogs?page[number]=2
```

so your code should access these params like:

```rb
params[:page][:number]
```

not:

```rb
params[:page]
```

Solution from above, using `ActiveModel::Serializers` will create links like this:

```
localhost:3000/v1/catalogs?page=2&per_page=50
```

So you can access pagination params like you want in your controller:

```rb
Catalog.page(params[:page]) # page number
Catalog.per(params[:per_page]) # page size
```